# Voila Ipyvuetify coud not instantiate widget error

Tags: jupyter-lab, voila, ipyvuetify

[image]

I got this error and really I could not find a solution. I have a working version of my program previously installed on a separated working environment. I could not make new installations work even with the same packages version.

Here is what I am doing(for having same versions)

```
pip install jupyterlab==3.4.3

pip install ipyvuetify==1.8.2

pip install voila==0.3.5

jupyter labextension install jupyter-vuetify

jupyter nbextension enable --py ipyvuetify

jupyter nbextension enable --py ipyvue

jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
voila es.ipynb --enable_nbextensions=True
```

no error is displayed on voila kernel

The file works properly if I run in jupyter lab like this

```
jupyter lab es.ipynb
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: I solve the issue by downgrading ipywidgets like  this pip install ipywidgets==7.7.1 jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager maybe the new version 8 give some problem

Answer (score 2):

I solve the issue by downgrading ipywidgets like this

```
pip install ipywidgets==7.7.1 
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
```

The new 8 version give some problem:
https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila/issues/1188